# How to center two divs in a one-page website?

Tags: css, html, image, alignment

The source code is here: http://bit.ly/17T0cps

[image]

I'm trying to make the BIG IMPACT text on top of the water splash. When at 100% view they are, but as I zoom out they look like the picture I provided.

Thanks

Comment: Why not make the splash image a background image on a div containing the `BIG IMPACT` text?

Comment: the splash will be an animated picture that slides in and out as you scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center any div use

`positon:absolute`  or `postion:relative` and then
    `top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;`

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

to the `img.splash`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I just added some margins to center it.

Comment: I have no idea how to center it. It seems my knowledge is proven wrong on this one. It's bothering me a lot. On the splash image I tried


margin: 0 50%;

This doesn't work..........